# Istio Authorization policy to exclude some apps in the same namespace

Tags: istio, istio-gateway

I need to setup an Authorization policy in a namespace "default" this should check if the JWT token is not present in header DENY access. So I setup a policy “allow-nothing” as below. This denies all requests without a valid token in the header. I want to exclude some apps in the same namespace from this rule. The apps allowed access needs to be in the same namespace. Can I create such a rule. Any pointers on this will help. Tried few things but have not been able to get this working.

```
kind: “AuthorizationPolicy”
metadata:
name: “allow-nothing”
namespace: default
spec:
selector:
matchLabels:
istio: ingressgateway
action: DENY
rules:

from:
source:
notRequestPrincipals: ["*"]
```

**EDIT**

This is the change I applied: `notHosts`, `notMethods` and `notPaths` into Operations

```
kind: "AuthorizationPolicy"
metadata:
  name: "deny-all"
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      istio: ingressgateway 
  action: DENY
  rules:
  - from:
    - source:
        notRequestPrincipals: ["*"]
  - to:
    - operation:
        notHosts: ["localhost"]
        notPaths: ["/ns/mypath"]
        notMethods: ["GET"]
```

When I apply this policy `DENY` action is still triggered. Note in the request I don't have the request principals. These are the ingress gateway logs

```
[2021-05-22T06:42:34.106Z] "GET /ns/mypath HTTP/1.1" 403 - rbac_access_denied_matched_policy[ns[istio-system]-policy[deny-all]-rule[0]] - "-" 0 19 0 - "w.x.y.z" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36" "7b4eb6d0-bdc0-943f-ad81-292b65809639" "localhost" "-" - - a.b.c.d:8080 w.x.y.z:34974 - -
```

Answer (score 1):

The portion `rbac_access_denied_matched_policy[ns[istio-system]-policy[deny-all]-rule[0]]` says that your traffic is matching that `deny-all` policy.

Now, to investigate the reason you need more information about what is going on. The first step is to enable debug logs, at least for the `rbac`: `istioctl pc log --level "rbac:debug" $POD_NAME.$NAMESPACE`. If you want to get more logs, you can omit the `rbac:debug` part but you'll get **a lot** of additional logs (not all of them are useful, but some of them are e.g., `jwt:debug,http:debug,http2:debug` could be useful).

After enabling such logs, there are few things that I would check:

- What information is the **target pod** getting from the **source pod**? Is the source pod really able to identify itself? You would probably see a line like `2021-05-14T13:35:24.759773Z debug   envoy rbac  checking connection: requestedServerName: ..., sourceIP: a.a.a.a:33142, directRemoteIP: a.a.a.a:33142,remoteIP: a.a.a.a:33142, localAddress: b.b.b.b:8443, ssl: none, dynamicMetadata:` . You have to pay attention to the details: here, for instance, the metadata information is empty and no ssl is being used. As a result, it is not really possible to determine which source principal is being used, and you may actually get a failure. (this **may** be the reason: allowing such logs should you in getting the real answer :) ). To solve this kind of issue, you need to enable mTLS.
- This is a bit more general and maybe not too relevant for your use case, but I think it's still worth mentioning (as it's something quite basic and often overlooked): in general, check what policies you are enforcing and how traffic is processed by istio sidecar. If you are using HTTP-based policies, make sure that traffic is being treated as such. Very often, HTTP policies are applied over traffic that is treated as plain TCP, and they will not match. Check https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/configuration/traffic-management/protocol-selection/ .

Answer (score 0):

You can try achieving that with `notHosts`, `notMethods`and `notPaths` in `rules.to.operation`.

For example

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: “AuthorizationPolicy”
metadata:
  name: “allow-nothing”
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      istio: ingressgateway
    action: DENY
rules:
- from:
  - source:
      notRequestPrincipals: ["*"]
- to:
  - operation:
      notHosts: ["*.example.com"]
      not_paths: ["/admin"]
```

should deny traffic to everything except host with `.example.com` suffix, and `/admin` path.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  Won't this still check the request prinicpals in the request and if it is not found deny . I tried this policy but it still shows "RBAC Access Denied "

Comment: Just to explain a bit more .I have edited my original question to indicate the change i have done .I have added notHosts, notMethods and notPaths in rules.to.operation as above. Can you please check if this is done correctly

Comment: Is it  possible to check why this rule is getting activated.Can I get more debug information.

Comment: Sure, look at @Mark answer, it shows you how to get more debug info.